# How to ignore tags within a paragraph?

Tags: html, css, tags, paragraph

Is it possible to have display tags with a paragraph? For example, I want to display the text '<c>' on my page within a p tag. however, the <c> is parsed as a tag instead of raw text.

```html
 <p1>Microsoft Windows<c></p1>
```

In this example, I want the <c> to be displayed as text rather than being used as a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to use [HTML codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html) for the symbols '<>'. The code for '<' is `&#60;` and that for '>' is `&#62;`, so your code should be:

```html
<p> Microsoft Windows &#60;c&#62;</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML Entitites](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).
The basic syntax goes like this:

```
<some_tag> Some text &entity_code </some_tag>
```

Talking about your case, it would go like

```
<p> Microsoft Windows &lt;c&gt;</p>
```