# How to print the word '<head>' inside an HTML <p> tag?

Tags: html

I have a plain `<p>` tag in my HTML. Inside this HTML tag I am trying to output text as follows:

> Place this code tag in the header of your website between `<head>` ...
> `</head>` in your page to show the notice to activate the functionality.

When I put this text inside the `<p>` tag as follows:

```
'<p>Place this code tag in the header of your website between <head> ... </head> in your page to show the notice to activate the functionality.</p>'
```

I render this wrong output:

```
Place this code tag in the header of your website between  ...   in your page to show the notice to activate the functionality.
```

As you can see the output did not print the ' head ' part.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore tags within a paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811134/how-to-ignore-tags-within-a-paragraph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `<` and `>` into the [entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) `&lt;` and `&gt;`. See also https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Example:

```html
<p>Place this code tag in the header of your website between &lt;head&gt; ... &lt;/head&gt; in your page to show the notice to activate the functionality.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To escape a character in html you need to use the ASCII value of that caracter so for the `<` and the `>` this is `&#60;` and `&#62;`

```html
<p>Place this code tag in the header of your website between &#60;head&#62; ... &#60;/head&#62; in your page to show the notice to activate the functionality.</p>
```